# Outputting the objects out of a vector<object*> c++

Tags: c++, oop, vector

I have two classes:

```
class Transactions
{
public:
    std::string type= "";
    
    double value = 0;
    void toString();

    Transactions(std::string transT, double transVal) {
        type = transT;
        value = transVal;
    }
};

class account
{
private:
    double balance = 0;
    std::vector <Transactions*> history{};
public:
    double get_balance() { return balance; }
    void set_balance(double value) { balance = value; }
    void toString();
    std::vector <Transactions*> get_history() { return history; }
    void set_history(Transactions* His) { history.push_back(His); }
};
```

I am in the process implementing the toString() method by doing:

```
void account::toString() {
    std::cout <<" | Current Account | Balance:" << std::to_string(get_balance()) << " | "  << std::endl
        << "Transaction History: ";

    for (Transactions* transaction : get_history())
    {
        std::cout << transaction->toString();
    }
}
```

but I get an error on the "<<" in the for loop. I also tried using an ordinary for loop but came to the same conclusions of "C++ no operator matches these operands. operand types are: std::ostream << void". I am fairly new to c++ coming from a c#/python background where pointers aren't a thing so I can only assume that is where the issue is being raised? That or that the vector is empty, but when the program is running it will be filled so I'm not sure how to circumvent that issue

also this is where account and transaction objects are made:

```
account* curAccount = new account(std::stoi(parameters[2]), accID++);
accountStore.push_back(curAccount);
std::cout << "account open! The account number is " << accID;
                        
Transactions* openingCTrans = new Transactions("Opening_Balance", std::stoi(parameters[2]));
curAccount->set_history(openingCTrans);
```

I know I didn't show the account or transaction constructors in the class but I don't think they're the issue

Comment: Your to_string method doesn’t return a string.

Comment: the error message says it precisely. `Transactions::toString` returns `void`. There is no way for `cout <<` to print a void

Comment: also, do not juggle raw pointers, use `std::shared_ptr` - this will give you lifecycle management like c#. not hard to do at all.

Comment: firstly) the toString() acts like it should, just a function that cout's something instead of returning is as a string. Secondly) is there anyway i can have the vector empty from the start of the program and be able to have this in the toString()?

Comment: no, we are talking about the line that defines `TRansanctions::toString`, you are referring to `account::toString` which calls `Transactions::toString`

Comment: ok I understand now I think thank you, realising I'm an idiot is fun

Comment: I'm still not sure why any of these toString() methods are using cout and not just returning a string. If you want a method that prints to stout, call it something like print(). Tbh, there's really no need for that inside a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this:

```
class Transactions
{
public:
    std::string type= "";
    
    double value = 0;
    void toString();

    Transactions(std::string transT, double transVal) {
        type = transT;
        value = transVal;
    }
};
```

should be

```
class Transactions
{
public:
    std::string type= "";
    
    double value = 0;
    std::string toString();   <<<<<============

    Transactions(std::string transT, double transVal) {
        type = transT;
        value = transVal;
    }
};
```

because you are doing

```
std::cout << transaction->toString();
```

ie, "please print the output of this function" so it has to return something printable

and use std::shared_ptr - you will thank me